# Why won't the Samurott Wonder Gift code work?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I am trying to get the event [Samurott](http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-news/three-stars-of-unova/) that is being distributed by Nintendo. But, when I try to verify the code, it says "The gift was not there..." What does this mean, and how do I fix it so I can get the event Pokemon?

Comment: What region are you in? What was the code you entered?

Comment: East Coast US, pokemon503

Comment: Sounds about right, that should have worked, afaik. I'll try it myself and report back here in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I was not able to receive the pokemon either, so I'd recommend waiting until at least tomorrow and check then. Samurott was supposed to be available starting february 5th and perhaps Nintendo is just being slow with their dates (wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: As Serebii states, now Samurott event is available with the usual code POKEMON503.

Comment: So they released it now?

Comment: I've found this news 20 minutes ago, according to Serebii if you live in US it will be available in a few hours. I linked the source in my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbanews.bulbagarden.net/wiki/North_American,_PAL_region_Hidden_Ability_starter_Pok%C3%A9mon_distribution_continues):

> Samurott's code will be **revealed** starting on February 5 via the Pokémon Trainer Club newsletter. Based on the Japanese distribution, the code is likely to be "POKEMON503", but this code does not work yet.

**EDIT**:

The serial code for the **Shell Armor Samurott** event is now active. The code, as expected, is *POKEMON503* and is currently live in Europe, Australia and will likely be in North America in a few hours. This code is valid until November 30th and will allow for you to receive the Samurott.

Source: [Serebii FB page](https://www.facebook.com/SerebiiNetPage/photos/a.272994882786806.65588.271717862914508/781202085299414)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Samurott's code has now been released for the US and Europe/Australia regions.

Start the game, and from the menu, go to Mystery Gift -> Receive Gift -> Get with Code, and enter the code **`POKEMON503`** to claim it.